# Disable the future dates in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Though same question exists here with similar answers, but none worked for me. Is there any other options to disable the future dates in jquery datepicker?

My code is:

```
$("#dob").datetimepicker({          
format: "dd-mm-yyyy",           
showMeridian: true,
autoclose: true,
minView: 2
});
```

I have tried using:

```
 maxDate: new Date
 maxDate: new Date()
```

or

```
 maxDate: 0
```

But none seems to work for me. I have been using the following version & files:

```
 jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.4
 bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Did you ty this: maxDate: $.now();

Comment: You're using bootstrap's datetimepicker, not jQuery. Hence, you need to check the correct js. Look at the duplicate-link I gave you.

Comment: @Amir https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker is this datetimepicker you are using?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie: Oh thanks for pointing it out. I was actually getting confused. I got the solution! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is example

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Try it

```
maxDate: '0d'
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem!